# The correct way to Malloc() space for a pointer to an array of int

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, heap-memory

Say I have a pointer to an array of `int`'s, like so: `int (*x)[3]`.
What is the correct way to allocate space for such a variable? For example, say I wanted space for 10 items (so that I can store a total of `10 * 3 = 30` values in x):

```
/* Is this the correct way? */
x = malloc(sizeof(x) * 10);

/* Will it allow me to do this? */
x[0][0] = 10;
x[0][1] = 20;
x[0][2] = 30;

x[1][0] = 40;
x[1][1] = 50;
x[1][2] = 60;

/* ... etc ... */
```

Or is there some other way to correctly malloc the memory for `x` (i.e. `x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10)` or `x = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 10)`?

Thanks.

Comment: Since `x` is a pointer type (e.g. `int *x`), the correct allocation is `int *x = malloc (sizeof *x * numreqd); if (!x)( {..handle error..}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to allocate space for the *pointer*, but for the object it points to. This is an important difference.

So you have a pointer type that points to a 2-d array with a second dimension of 3 (let's call this *columns*) and you want the array to have 10 *rows*. In C, *n-dimensional arrays* are stored contiguously, that means, they take exactly as much room as all of their elements together. So the formula gets pretty simple:

```
x = malloc(3 * 10 * sizeof(int));
```

---

*edit:* if you want to avoid *magic numbers*, you could also work with a `typedef`:

```
typedef int inttriplet[3];
// [...]
inttriplet *x;
x = malloc(10 * sizeof(inttriplet));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to not forget to verify the memory of allowance and to not forget to free it after having used it.
However, it is not really the problem. I wonder if the following instructions are valid. Because we could write in the following way "no":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZEMAX 3
typedef int intTab[SIZEMAX];


int main( void ){

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    intTab *p = NULL;
    extern int errno;

    errno = 0;
    if( NULL == (p = malloc( SIZEMAX * sizeof *p) ) ){
        (void)fprintf( stdout, "(%d)\t:%s\n\t:%s\n", errno,
                      "Erreur alloca mem", strerror(errno) );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    memset(p, 0, (SIZEMAX * SIZEMAX * sizeof **p));

    for( i = 0; i < SIZEMAX; i++ ){
        for( j = 0; j < SIZEMAX; j++ )
            (void)fprintf(stdout, "Tab[%d][%d]\t:%d\n",
                          i, j, p[i][j] );
    }

    for( i = 0; i < SIZEMAX; i++ )
        free( p[i] );

    free( p );
    p = NULL;

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```